# Getting Scripting Error with JSP, Just trying to display txt file contents to browser window

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working on a homework assignment for a course. I have most of the project set up to get information from the user and such, but I want to display a simple text file to the browser as the last piece. No matter what I try, I cannot get it to work.

I have to use either JSP or HTML, NOTHING ELSE. I would've much rather used another language or frankly anything that isn't as utterly infuriating as Java or its related pieces, but for educational purposes I cannot in this assignment.

My code for the JSP page that displays the results is this:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>

<%
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("WEB-INF/EmailList.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(line);
    }
    out.flush();
    input.close();

%>
```

I continue to get this error:

```
Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, 
&lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) 
are disallowed here.
```

After countless hours of Googling and looking through other posts, I cannot seem to find an answer that makes any sense to me about this. All I want to do is display a simple text file to the screen. Pretty much every example I see is from 5 years or more ago when certain things must've been allowed. I am currently running latest version of Netbeans and the Tomcat Server 8 on Mac OSX 10.11.5.

Can anyone maybe provide an answer that makes more sense than everything else I have read? I apologize for the frustration, this is one of the worst set up classes I have taken so far, and I typically cannot even get code to run so the fact that I am this far is impressive in itself. The teacher is also no help at all, and the book is on an entirely different tangent than the assignments posted biweekly.

Comment: You are sure you are getting the txt file? You will have to do getServletContext().getRealPath("/") with a "/WEB-INF...".

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that your `web.xml` has specified `<scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>`, which means you can't do Java code in the JSP, i.e. `<% code %>` is not allowed.

As the message say (formatted and ordered for clarity):

```
Scripting elements are disallowed here:
  <%!
  <%=
  <%                       <-- That's what you are doing
  <jsp:declaration
  <jsp:expression
  <jsp:scriptlet
```

Remove the `<scripting-invalid>` tag, or change value to `false`.

Or better yet: ***DON'T***

Write you code in a servlet, where it belongs.

Comment: For the purpose of this class, I just said scripting invalid was false. I appreciate it wholeheartedly.